# Which criteria should I adopt when deciding to implement hook_xmlrpc() or supporting the Services module?

Tags: services

If I should decide between implementing [`hook_xmlrpc()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_xmlrpc/7) and supporting the [Services module](http://drupal.org/project/services), what should I consider on taking this decision?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider carefully your

- audience
- goals
- time
- alternatives

Is your audience going to know how to make calls to your implementation in hook_xmlrpc? Many developers today are familiar with using RESTful services, but I would argue the number working with xml-rpc services is dwindling. Is your audience willing to install the services module to use your functionality, or would they more likely want a solution that is already available in core?

Is your goal to do something simple, such as interface with Drupal's blog system? If so, then hook_xmlrpc may be a better approach. Is your goal to create a fully featured web service for integration with external apps? Then, you may be better off using the services module.

Do you have the time to learn setup and learn the Services module? This could take more time than using a simple hook_xmlrpc, but it could also save you much time in the long run.

Have you considered the alternatives such as [Rest Server](http://drupal.org/project/rest_server)?